# How to avoid the automatic cut of an image?

Tags: graphics, overleaf

The figure has been exported from matlab and it has the size: 560 * 315. It is in vector graphics format .eps.
**The problem is that the figure is cut uncorrectly on the right side**. I've noticed of this by viewing the last number on the horizontal axis, as shown in the following image:

[image: zooming]

The image from which I've extracted the particular is:
[image]

I've this problem only for some images.

Here there is a sample code in which I've inserted two images and in which I've the problem only with one of them:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{figures}

\begin{document}

%Image with the problem
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{es5_vel_ang.eps}
\caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ ed $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
\label{fig:es5_vel_ang}
\vspace{4mm}
\end{figure} 

%Image without problem
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.90]{es5_virata.eps}
\caption{Manvora di virata.}
\label{fig:es5_vel_lin}
\vspace{4mm}
\end{figure} 


\end{document}
```

Here the two images files:
[Images of code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18iw0zgA7SD1ZI1J1aHfp0oWBiRPLg0vs?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why don't you try `scale=0.99` (or a bit less if necessary)?

Comment: Can you set a border/margin in MatLab? I am not familiar with MatLab, but maybe this (https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/474979-setting-desired-margins-and-ratio-for-plot) helps you?

Comment: @Bernard The issue isn't related to the scale: it's rather the output of `epstopdf` which cuts the image a bit. I guess the eps bounding box isn't quite right.

Comment: @campa: Didn't know that. But maybe directly converting to pdf with Ghostscript would work smoothly?

Comment: @Bernard I tried to reduce scale but it does not work.

Comment: @campa i removed the package "epstopdf" but the problem is always present.

Comment: As I suggested in my previous comment, converting to pdf with Ghostcript beforehand might work? Unless Matlab has a pdf export?

Comment: I never claimed that removing the package would solve the problem; in fact, loading the package hasn't been necessary since at least 10 years, and the program is run in background. As I said, my guess is that the eps files generated by matlab have a somewhat small bounding box, but I can't investigate this issue right now. Maybe I'll find some time later.

Comment: you can probably add some padding in matlab so the bounding box isn't too small, or better export to PDF and avoid having to convert from eps altogether. In any case it isn't really a latex problem, if the image is already clipped before latex includes it then it can not do much about that.

Comment: @campa thanks for your answers!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I'll try to change the margins in the matlab code. I tried to export in pdf but if I do not cut the image in the A4 page, all the page in inserted in my overleaf document and so I have to make the additional step of cutting the image.

Comment: Since I would avoid to edit figures in matlab, is not it possbile to customize margins cutting directly in overleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue in matlab by using the option "-loose" of the function "print".